# Insert variables to minimize code

Tags: java, if-statement, minimize

I am facing a strange problem.

```
if ( c2==c1){
    c3 *= 2 ; 
    System.out.println( c3 ) ; 
    .....
}
```

I want to insert c3*2 in the println statment. But

```
if ( c2==c1){
    System.out.println( c3*2 ) ;
```

gives me a different result.

Here is the whole code:

```
        public static void main(String [] args) {

           int c1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) ;
           int c2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]) ;
           int c3 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]) ;

/*  1 */       if ( c1 != c3 ){
/*  2 */        if (c2==c1){
/*  3 */              
/*  4 */              System.out.println(c3 + c2 ) ; 
/*  5 */              c3 *= c2 ; 
/*  6 */        }

/*  7 */       }else{ 
/*  8 */        if ( c2==c1){
/*  9 */                    c3 *= 2 ; 
/* 10 */                    System.out.println( c3 ) ; 
/* 11 */                    c3 *= c2 ; 
/* 12 */            if ( c1 < c2 ) c2 += 7 ;
/* 13 */                   else c2 += 5 ; 
/* 14 */               }}

/* 15 */       System.out.println( c1+c2+c3) ;     
        }          
        .....
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you leave the variable declaration before? What result it gives you?

Comment: it's the same here. Your are not showing everything.

Comment: *What* different result, and different from *what?* You haven't even posted the declaration of c3. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `c3 *= 2;` it will change the value of `c3` which will print a different value from the last line `System.out.println( c1+c2+c3);`. So you need to follow the logic of your program.

Answer (score 7):

```
c3 *= 2; 
System.out.println( c3 ) ;
```

would print the same thing as:

```
System.out.println( c3 * 2 ) ;
```

but the crucial difference is that in the first case the value of the `c3` variable will be modified (multiplied by 2) while in the second it will stay the same.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to get different result depending on the type of your variable - remember `*=` (and also `++`, `--`, etc) casts the result to the same type as `c3`. For example:

```
byte b = 100;
System.out.println(b*2); // 200
b*=2;
System.out.println(b); // -56
```

Example: http://ideone.com/ojKfA

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify variable and print it at the same time you can do it like this:

```
System.out.println(c3 *= 2);
```